# c++ vector of derived class calls constructor only once

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, vector, constructor

If I make a **size 2** `std::vector` of a derived class, the constructor is called only once. If I make a size 2 vector of a base class, the constructor is called twice.

I usually wouldn't post the complete code that duplicates an issue, but in this case it can be made quite short:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    Base() { std::cout << "base constructor" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { std::cout << "derived constructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Base> base(2);
    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Derived> derived(2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above for me is:

```
base constructor
----------------
base constructor
derived constructor
```

Why is the output not the following:

```
base constructor
base constructor
----------------
derived constructor
derived constructor
```

I'm using gcc 4.5.2 on Linux.

Comment: I guess it's only making one object?

Comment: Perfect testcase. Well done and thanks for it; never apologise for it.

Comment: Rolled back: I think the version with the dashes is better, no?

Comment: For me the dashed line appears after the first output of `base constructor`, and after the dashed line appears (in effect) `base constructor \nderived constructor`.  That's because creating an object of type `Base` requires a call to the `Base` constructor, and creating an object of type `Derived` requires a call to both the `Base` and the `Derived` constructor.

Comment: Yes, I added the dashed line without running the code. Once I did run the code I saw my error in reasoning as @Kerek SB describes in the answer.

Comment: Actually, I must wonder why you decided to test this **only** with the value `2`. If you had tried even 3 or 5, you would have seen immediately that something is off.

Comment: @Kerrek, I have a much larger complicated piece of code from which this concern arose, I tried to show the simplest piece of code that showed the problem I was having. I spent very little time in searching for a solution **on purpose** so that my question would genuinely reflect a lack of understanding and thus might help someone in the future with the same concern. Obviously, I would've found this "bug" after 5 minutes of further testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're deceiving yourself: A single default construction of the derived object calls *both* constructors.

Now, what you are *not* seeing is the **copy constructor**, which does in fact get called twice in both cases.

The constructor of `vector` that you're calling makes *one* default construction of its value type, and then *copies* that into each element:

```
//std::vector<Derived> v(2);

std::vector<Derived> v(2, Derived()); // same thing!
```

Comment: Why is the copy constructor used for the derived class and a default constructor used for the base class?

Comment: @Lex: No, no, the copy constructor is used to populate the vector. A single default-constructed object is made as a prototype, and then all the vector elements are copied from that. Only `Derived::Derived(const Derived&)` gets used for the copying.

Comment: Add printing output to the copy constructors and you shall see!

Comment: but why does `std::vector<Base> base(2);` call the default constructor twice not once then.

Comment: @Lex: It doesn't!! Separate the test cases into two programs, you'll see! It is the construction of `Derived()` that calls one base and one derived constructor.

Comment: Got it. Perfect. So the lesson is if you need a special default constructor, you should also write a copy constructor and assignment operator. Specifically, in my actual code I have a `std::shared_ptr` that needs to be allocated upon construction, and I didn't write a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @Lex: No, not necessarily. You can have many constructors, but there's not usually a need to write the Big Three (Copy/Delete/Assign) unless you have some explicit resources management, which should then be in a single-responsibility class. In fact, the library provides so many good tools that if you find yourself writing your own copy constructor or destructor, you might well be doing it wrong...

Comment: Why is copy constructor used as opposed to the default I wonder? See @sashang answer for the VC++ 2010 difference.

Comment: @Lex: The C++98 library design only has this one version of a constructor that fills a given number of elements, and it does that by copying from a prototype. That's just the design. C++11 adds other versions that construct elements in place. Compile with `-std=c++0x` to see the difference.

Comment: Actually I did try it with -std=c++0x, and the result was the same but that's probably because I'm using GCC 4.5. It looks like for GCC 4.6 the constructors change as @shashang answer describes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of an extension on what Kerrek wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
   public:
      Base() { std::cout << "base constructor" << std::endl; }
      virtual ~Base() {
      }
      Base(const Base&){
         std::cout << "copy base constructor" << std::endl;
      }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
       Derived() { std::cout << "derived constructor" << std::endl; }
       Derived(const Derived& d):Base((const Base) d){
          std::cout << "copy derived constructor" << std::endl;
       }
};

int main() {
   std::vector<Base> base(2);
   std::cout << std::endl;
   std::vector<Derived> derived(2);

   return 0;
}
```

The output from this is:

```
base constructor
copy base constructor
copy base constructor

base constructor
derived constructor
copy base constructor
copy derived constructor
copy base constructor
copy derived constructor
```

Comment: Did you mean to put the `std::cout` into the `Base` copy constructor and not its destructor?

Answer (score 2):

This is the output I get from VC++ 2010:

```
base constructor
base constructor
base constructor
derived constructor
base constructor
derived constructor
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Whereas with (GCC) 4.6.1

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
sashan@cyclops cpp  $ ./test
base constructor
base constructor
derived constructor
```

So it looks like it's an implementation difference....which is kinda puzzling.

### Update

Compiling with c++0x gives:

```
sashan@cyclops cpp  1 $  g++ -std=c++0x -o test test.cpp
sashan@cyclops cpp  $ ./test
base constructor
base constructor
base constructor
derived constructor
base constructor
derived constructor
```

Which supports Kerrek SB's comments and answer.

Comment: VC+2010 isn't C++98 -- they have some partial C++11 support, and along with that come some new, emplacing constructors for the containers... this may well be a result of that.

Comment: You can get emplacing behaviour in GCC as well if you compile with `-std=c++0x`. Then you'll also get the direct constructions and no copies. (I never thought about this, actually, thanks! By just turning on C++11 you get better efficiency!)